How to download a .pom file from the gradle plugin repository?
I want to build a project with a couple of gradle plugins on the machine without internet connection. I have a private maven repo with all of dependencies for this project, except .pom file for gradle plugins. How can I grab it from plugins.gradle.org and publish to my private repo?

This code, using Kotlin DSL, defines a task getThePoms which obtains the POMs from the artifacts added to configuration pomConfiguration1 and hosted at the Gradle Plugin Portal, and copies them to build/poms.
Note you need to specify the artifact coordinates in the dependencies block, not the Gradle plugin ids, which are part of a separate lookup mechanism.
val pomConfigurationName = "pomConfiguration"

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

val pomConfiguration = configurations.register(pomConfigurationName) {
    isTransitive = false // We only want the declared dependencies
}

dependencies {
    pomConfigurationName("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.0")
    pomConfigurationName("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:2.0.0")
}

tasks.register<Copy>("getThePoms") {
    val componentIds = pomConfiguration.get().resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.map { it.id.componentIdentifier }
    val artifactQueryResult = dependencies.createArtifactResolutionQuery()
        .forComponents(componentIds)
        .withArtifacts(MavenModule::class.java, MavenPomArtifact::class.java)
        .execute()
    val pomFiles = artifactQueryResult.resolvedComponents
        .flatMap { component -> component.getArtifacts(MavenPomArtifact::class) }
        .map { result -> (result as ResolvedArtifactResult).file }
    from(pomFiles)
    into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("poms"))
}


1 Here using the Kotlin Gradle plugin and Kotlin serialization plugin as examples.
